# Added button in the table changes the height of the table row

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a button in the table.

```
<tr key={key}>
                <td align="center"> <input type="checkbox" name="myTextEditBox" value="checked" /></td>
                <td>{item.technology}</td>
                <td>17</td>
                <td title={item.jdName} className="jd-name-container justify-content-center align-items-center">
                  <div className="jdName">{item.jdName}</div>
                  {(key + 1 === 1) && <div className="badge new-badge badge-warning-custom">New</div>}
                </td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>
                  <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">delete</a>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>


#job-table table {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    width: 100%;
}

#job-table thead {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

#job-table tbody {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: block;
    height: 285px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#job-table tr {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

So now,when I tried to add button it changes the height of the row,

So, it looks like,

[image]

[image]

How can I resolve this ?

So, I actually have an option that I can set the height of a row as a height to the button or else the fixed height to the button. SO, which of these solutions will be better, I also want to support it on the higher resolutions as well.

Comment: Best solution is change button size to make it looks pretty. Think of that, do you like when button is larger than text 3 or 4 times? I don't think so.

Comment: but is it good to set the height of button fixed ?

Comment: You can use `btn-sm` class so it won't be fixed

Comment: What I did is used height: 100%